# How do I access third table via Many-to-Many Relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, laravel-5.4

I am developing an eCommerce Website using Laravel 5.4. Here is database structure:

```
Products Table: 

ID - Product Name
1  - Test Mobile



Attributes Table

ID - AttributeName
1  - Network



AttributeValues Table

ID - AttributeID - AttributeValue
1  - 1           - 2G
2  - 1           - 3G
3  - 1           - 4G



ProductAttributes Table

ID - AttributeValueID - ProductID
1  - 2                - 1
2  - 3                - 1
```

Here is the relations:

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function attributeValues() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\AttributeValue', 'attribute_product');
    }

}
```

Attribute.php

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }


    public function values() {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
    }
}
```

AttributeValue.php

```
class AttributeValue extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function attribute() {
        return $this->belongsTo( App\Attribute::class );
    }

}
```

I can access the Product Attributes Values by using the following code:

```
$p = App\Product::find(1);
$p->attributeValues;
```

Through this code I am able to retrieve Product Attribute values. But I can access the `attributeValues` along with the Attribute names? In other words how I can access the Attribute table along with the attribute values? Which relationship will be used?

Any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @Thomas Can you please post a sample code?

Comment: I can't at this moment because it takes too much time to understand your current problem exactly. Can you simplify the question to what you expect as output?

Comment: @Thomas I want to access the Product Attributes with the pair of Attribute name and value. i.e: Network: 3G.

Comment: @GopaThemes Something is not so clear with the table description you gave. One is that, there is no reference maybe, `id` of product on `attributes` or did you miss it in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I once did something like this with `load` method i.e

```
$p = App\Product::find(1);
$p->load('attributeValues.attribute');
```

So for every *attributeValue*, get corresponding *attribute*
It should work for you too...

> PS: I can't bet this is the best way to do it. But I have used this technique for a Laravel 5.2 project

Answer (score 0):

you are using it wrong place , use the same name you used for describing relation in model.

```
$product = App\Product::with('attributeValues.attribute')->find(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Product belonsToMany AttributeValue, AttributeValue Should belongsToMany Product.

**Product Model:**

```
public function attributeValues() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\AttributeValue', 'attribute_product');
    }
```

**AttributeValue Model:**

```
public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }

public function attribute() {
    return $this->belongsTo( App\Attribute::class );
}
```

**Attribute Model:**

```
  public function values() {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
    }
```

And,

```
$product = App\Product::find(1);
foreach($product->attributeValues as $attributeValue)
{
   echo $attributeValue;
   echo $attributeValue->attribute;
}
```